# Retain answer on how to use Windows registry?

Tags: discussion

Should [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/885178/54568) be retained or deleted? It cross references a different answer that describes a registry hack and adds specifics on how to use `regedit` to perform the registry modification?

The answer is reasonable quality, especially for a newbie; its technical shortcomings that could easily be improved with minor editing. The question I am driving at here is the broader one of whether supplemental answers that provide step-by-step instructions on how to make registry hacks are desirable.

Comment: The answer is extremely low quality, its basically a duplicate, of the already existing answer.  I don't find duplicate answers very helpful personally.

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be deleted.

1. In principle, every answer that describes a registry modification could have steps on how to make the change. This would lead to many very similar supplemental answers.
2. Making a mistake when editing the registry can cause major problems with Windows. Microsoft support articles always include a warning before providing instructions on making registry changes. There is some safety in not including details steps, since it is likely that the reader will already be competent or if not, will do a web search on how to edit the registry and likely find instructions and appropriate warnings, including backing up the registry.

Comment: I do not think so, and I do not know why you feel the need to worry about it?  Seems like it was a FAN of your answer who proceeded to follow your answer and in doing so wrote down the steps they followed completly to do it.  As for #2 , it is confusing when you did not place any disclaimer yourself to backup the Key first before deletion in your own answer.  So far I see the whole thing as a Win-Win the whole of the answer is there. It is everything one might need to do the removal ('cept the backup part)

Comment: @Psycogeek I find the two extrema to be safe: (1) Don't say how to modify the registry (in which case a user's ignorance and need to Google the how-to will protect him - this is why I didn't include a disclaimer), and (2) tell how to modify the registry, but with full safety disclosures. Unsafe is the middle ground where the user learns just enough to be dangerous. Although both extrema are safe, I am concerned about disclosure overload if every registry-related answer has instructions and a necessary caveat.

Comment: I added an appropriate *warning* comment to both answers

Comment: IMO there's no new information, so it should have been an edit to the existing answer (to make it better) or a comment. All it is (to me) is basic instructions on how to use Regedit, using the already given answer as an example.

Comment: @DavidPostill I was thinking something more simple and less ominous :-)   Because in this situation it is a deletion.  Simple like:  Export this specific branch of the registry (as backup), then delete these items.  .  & Edward, yea I do get what your saying, if they do not know how to edit a registry, then . . . ?  they wont edit the registry, they will use the GUI method.  Many end up editing the registry because it was the Only way to make some changes.  That is how I got started, no choice, and trial and error.

Comment: @Psycogeek please feel free to prove an alternate text that is less ominous ;)